# App using socket.io and Node.js works locally but not deployed to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io, multiplayer, phaser-framework

Tried other solutions I could find such as adding process.env.PORT and also looked at heroku's guide on socket.io.

The Phaser.io game my group is making works perfectly locally, however when we deploy to heroku there is a bug where only the first player connected will see the other players, and only for a brief moment as well. After that short period, the players freeze.

My question is, does anyone have any clue what could potentially be causing the issue? Is it something wrong with our implementation of socket.io?

Thank you in advance for your help. Extremely confused as to what is causing this issue.

Here is a deployed version: https://death-road-to-toronto.herokuapp.com/

Here is the repo if you'd like: https://github.com/Road-To-Capstone/CapstoneMultiplayer/

Here are the code snippets relevant to socket and express
Index.js

```
const config = require('./config');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');


const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

app.use('/', express.static(config.publicDir));
//-socket
const players = require('./players.js');
const missiles = require('./missiles.js');
const zombies = require('./zombies.js');

io.on('connection', socket => {
     -------
});
//=socket
server.listen(process.env.PORT || config.port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${config.port}`);
});


//creating new zombie id
function newZombieId() {
    let id = new Date();
    return id.getTime();
}
```

config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    port: 3000,
    publicDir: path.join(__dirname, '../public'),
    game: {
        start: {
            x: 400,
            y: 400
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT1** : I made a funny discovery while playing around with socket.io and heroku. So if I connect with another computer to the deployed version on heroku, then click on console (just to freeze the game). Anyone at that point can join and everything works perfectly, just like in the local copy.

Does anyone know why? If not what can I do as a work around? Perhaps implement a lobby system and allow all players to join and start at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem! Going to leave my question and the solution here for prosperity, incase other people want to implement a multiplayer game using Phaser and socket.io on Heroku and also run into issues.

We added this to the index.html file `</script type ="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>` which allows heroku to access the socket library.

It actually wasn't a setup issue with socket.io, it was our logic. When a player detects movement it instantly tries to socket.broadcast that a player moved. However, when other players first connect, they don't have time to retrieve all the players information from the server side. Thus the broadcast would cause an error where "player" is undefined. Adding a conditional statement fixed our issue.

The code in it's entirety is going to be left on github if you want to investigate further.